# Ruby to load profile component in selected lines

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I have a question in writing ruby code which can do 3d modeling in `SketchUp` program that I would like my profile components to stretch the lengths in the selected lines for creating glass curtain wall systems of stick and unitized system. For now, I knew that there's a method for creating only one connected line, but does not have for multiple and separated lines yet. Therefore, I'm looking for a way to write a code to do in one click of sample profile component and then load on multiple lines.

Is there any suggestion to do this kind of code ?. I have been trying to solve codes, but can't do in on my own since I'm so new in programming.

Answer (score 0):

The Follow Me feature only extrudes a profile along one segment. If you have multiple branching segments you need to go about it differently. One method you can try is to sort out the different segments and create them separately as groups - they should each result in a solid object where you could then use the solid boolean operation which was introduced in SketchUp 8 Pro.